# Proving Existence of Multiplicative Inverse

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

I am given 2 sets.

Set $R = \{a+b\sqrt2: a,b \in \Bbb{Z}\}$
and Set $U = \{\alpha \in R: N(\alpha) = 1\}$
where $N(\alpha) = a^2 - 2b^2$

I am supposed to show that $U$ is a subgroup of $\Bbb{R}^x$ which means the set of units over all real numbers.

I was able to show that $1 \in U$ and set $U$ is closed under multiplication, but I still have to show that every element of $U$ has a multiplicative inverse, and I have no clue how to do so.

If you could let me know, I would greatly appreciate it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the norm as $N(\alpha) = (a + b \sqrt 2)(a - b \sqrt 2)$. If $a + b \sqrt 2 \in R$, then $a - b \sqrt 2 \in R$.

Then if $N(\alpha) = 1$, you have $(a + b \sqrt 2)(a - b\sqrt 2) = 1$, and thus the inverse of $a + b \sqrt 2$ is $a - b \sqrt 2$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(a+b\sqrt{2})(a-b\sqrt{2})=a^2-2b^2=1$. View this as $x\cdot y=1$ in $U$.